# Flask Refresh page after file download

Tags: python, flask

This code will take a PDF file and Return a .txt file as download:

```py
from flask import Flask, make_response, request, render_template
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os

from processing import get_numbers

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def my_page():
    if request.method == "POST":
        f = request.files.get("file")
        if f:
            filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
            file_path = os.path.join('temp_files', filename)
            f.save(file_path)
            output_data = get_numbers(file_path)
            response = make_response(output_data)
            response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = \
                f"attachment; filename={filename[:-4]}.txt"
            os.remove(file_path)

            return response

    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

How can I manage to reload the page after the file is downloaded (after **return response**)?

Comment: if you trying to download it from your local then you can try `send_file` of flask and you can use `redirect`.

Comment: how would that work exactly? both `send_file` and and `redirect`would need to be returned or not?

Comment: Why do you need to download the file when you are uploading itself?